# Convert a long hex string in to int array with sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I have an input like

```
char *input="00112233FFAA";
uint8_t output[6];
```

What is the easiest way to convert `input` into `output` with `sscanf`? (prefer 1 line with no loop) The solution I have in mind doesn't scale to 20+ hex string.

```
sscanf(input, "%x%x%x%x%x",output[0], output[1]....output[5]);
```

Comment: sscanf(input, "%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x",&output[0], &output[1], ..., &output[5]);

Comment: Note that using `%x` to parse into a `uint8_t` location can cause memory corruption because it actually expects an `unsigned int`.

Comment: I'd call that a byte array or octet string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why `scanf` if this can be easily written by hand:

```
const size_t numdigits = strlen(input) / 2;

uint8_t * const output = malloc(numdigits);

for (size_t i = 0; i != numdigits; ++i)
{
  output[i] = 16 * toInt(input[2*i]) + toInt(intput[2*i+1]);
}

unsigned int toInt(char c)
{
  if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return      c - '0';
  if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') return 10 + c - 'A';
  if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') return 10 + c - 'a';
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: The standard doesn't technically guarantee consecutive alphabet characters, but within the range A-F your code should work in EBCDIC on the two computers still using that.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: Indeed, there are a few assumptions there about the permissible encodings. Worst case you can replace the `toInt` body by a lookup table...

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to use a loop, then you need to explicitly write out all six (or twenty) array locations (although `%x` is not the correct conversion character - it expects a pointer to `unsigned int` as its corresponding argument).  If you don't want to write them all out, then you need to use a loop - it can be quite simple, though:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    sscanf(&input[i * 2], "%2hhx", &output[i]);
```

Comment: The `hh` didn't do the trick for me. I had to parse into a temporary array of `unsigned int` and then copy manually to the `uint8_t` array.

Comment: @ChrisWue: Probably you don't have a C99-conforming standard library (eg. the Microsoft C library).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternate implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define _base(x) ((x >= '0' && x <= '9') ? '0' : \
         (x >= 'a' && x <= 'f') ? 'a' - 10 : \
         (x >= 'A' && x <= 'F') ? 'A' - 10 : \
            '\255')
#define HEXOF(x) (x - _base(x))

int main() {
    char input[] = "00112233FFAA";
    char *p;
    uint8_t *output;

    if (!(sizeof(input) & 1)) { /* even digits + \0 */
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Cannot have odd number of characters in input: %d\n",
            sizeof(input));
        return -1;
    }

    output = malloc(sizeof(input) >> 1);

    for (p = input; p && *p; p+=2 ) {
            output[(p - input) >> 1] =
            ((HEXOF(*p)) << 4) + HEXOF(*(p+1));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@caf already had a good simple idea.

However I had to use %02x and now it's working fine:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    sscanf(&input[i * 2], "%02x", &output[i]);
```