# Netezza SQL convert VARCHAR to binary string

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a bitmap stored as a `VARCHAR` in Netteza. Need to convert that `VARCHAR` to a binary string in Netezza.

Input (Netezza col value - `VARCHAR` ) = `'0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF'`

Desired output (`VARCHAR`)->

```
'1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
```

Is there a way to do this using Netezza query ?

I tried

```
SELECT CAST('0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF' AS VARBINARY(64) );
```

but that throws an error

> ERROR [HY000]ERROR: Cannot cast type 'VARCHAR' to 'VARBINARY'

Comment: It seems like you are wanting to convert a varchar that holds a hexadecimal representation into  either A) a binary representation of that hex value or B) a varchar representation of a binary representation using ASCII characters '0' and '1'.  Can you clarify if you want A or B?

Comment: B is what I'm looking for. 
 
Just to expand on this - eventually what I need to do with this is as following - 1- find position of the first 1 in the binary string ( 0 in case of '0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF' ). 2- find the count of 1's in the binary string ( 64 in case of '0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF') - from that perspective B is probably sufficient

Comment: It looks like an explicit conversion would be required but [this isn't supported by Netezza](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_supported_im_ex_casts.html). So looks (to me) like the conversion may have to be done manually...

Comment: @SteveChambers - could you please provide more direction on doing this manually ?

Comment: @user3206440 Not exactly sure the best way to go here but perhaps a User Defined Function in some vein that loops through the string and builds up the binary equivalent? See [this PDF](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/form/anonymous/api/library/1b6a2624-dc86-4856-b4ed-cdda6bfdecda/document/bae7dae4-8fc8-439d-a804-c9498dc09f18/media/01_ch.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert a hex string into binary data and store it in either a VARCHAR or VARBINARY column.  I tend to prefer VARCHAR because of the rather limited CASTs that are available for VARBINARY.

To convert a hex string to binary and stored it in a VARCHAR, use the hextoraw function provided with the SQL Extension Toolkit.  This is included with Netezza but must be configured and made available by your administrator.

To convert a hex string to binary and store it in a VARBINARY, use the hex_to_binary function included with Netezza (added in v 7.2).

```
drop table test_table if exists;
DROP TABLE
create table test_table (col1 varchar(50), col2 varbinary(50));
CREATE TABLE

insert into test_table values (hextoraw('464F4F'), hex_to_binary('464F4F'));
INSERT 0 1

select * from test_table;
 COL1 |   COL2
------+-----------
 FOO  | X'464F4F'
(1 row)
```

From there you'll need a UDF to handle the bit calculations that you want to do.  I've put together three simple UDFs that I believe will suit your purpose.

FirstBit returns the position of the first non-zero bit.
BitCount returns the total count of non-zero bits.
CharToBase2 converts a binary values in a VARCHAR of 1s and 0s.

I think the first two get the end result that you need without the third, but in case you still wanted that, it's here.

```
select firstbit(hextoraw('0000')), bitcount(hextoraw('0000')), chartobase2(hextoraw('0000'));
FIRSTBIT | BITCOUNT |   CHARTOBASE2
----------+----------+------------------
       -1 |        0 | 0000000000000000
(1 row)

select firstbit(hextoraw('0001')), bitcount(hextoraw('0001')), chartobase2(hextoraw('0001'));
 FIRSTBIT | BITCOUNT |   CHARTOBASE2
----------+----------+------------------
       15 |        1 | 0000000000000001
(1 row)

select firstbit(hextoraw('FFFF')), bitcount(hextoraw('FFFF')), chartobase2(hextoraw('FFFF'));
 FIRSTBIT | BITCOUNT |   CHARTOBASE2
----------+----------+------------------
        0 |       16 | 1111111111111111
(1 row)
```

Here are the sources for each.  Please note that I am a terrible C++ coder, and would likely be fired if that were my job, so caveat emptor.

**BitCount.cpp**

```
#include "udxinc.h"
#include <string.h>

using namespace nz::udx;

class BitCount : public Udf
{
    public:
        static Udf* instantiate();

    ReturnValue evaluate()
    {
        StringArg* str = stringArg(0);
        int32 retval = 0;


        for(int i=0; i< str->length; i++)
                {

                for (int y=7; y>=0 ; y--)
                        {

                        if ((str->data[i] & (unsigned char)pow(2,y)) > 0)
                                {
                                        retval++;

                                }

                        }
                }

        NZ_UDX_RETURN_INT32(retval);
    }

};

Udf* BitCount::instantiate()
{
    return new BitCount;
}
```

**FirstBit.cpp**

```
#include "udxinc.h"
#include <string.h>

using namespace nz::udx;

class FirstBit : public Udf
{
    public:
        static Udf* instantiate();

    ReturnValue evaluate()
    {
        StringArg* str = stringArg(0);
        int32 retval = -1;


        for(int i=0; i< str->length; i++) {

                for (int y=7; y>=0 ; y--) {

                        if ((str->data[i] & (unsigned char)pow(2,y)) > 0)
                                {
                                        retval = i*8 + 7 - y;

                                }

                        if (retval > -1) break;
                }
                if (retval > -1)         break;
                }

        NZ_UDX_RETURN_INT32(retval);
    }

};

Udf* FirstBit::instantiate()
{
    return new FirstBit;
}
```

**CharToBase2.cpp**

```
#include "udxinc.h"
#include <string.h>

using namespace nz::udx;

class CharToBase2 : public Udf
{
    public:
        static Udf* instantiate();

    ReturnValue evaluate()
    {
        StringArg* str = stringArg(0);
        StringReturn* result = stringReturnInfo();
        result->size = str->length*8;
        //unsigned char stringbyte = 0 ;


        for(int i=0; i< str->length; i++)
                {


                  for (int y=7; y>=0 ; y-- )
                        {

                         if ((str->data[i] & (unsigned char)pow(2,y)) == 0) {
                                        result->data[i*8 + 7 - y] = '0'; }
                                else {
                                        result->data[i*8 + 7 - y] = '1';        }
                        }

                }

        NZ_UDX_RETURN_STRING(result);
    }

    uint64 calculateSize() const
    {
        return sizerStringSizeValue(sizerStringArgSize(0)*8);
    }
};

Udf* CharToBase2::instantiate()
{
    return new CharToBase2;
}
```

Finally, here are the scripts I used to compile and install each.

**install_firstbit.sh DBNAME**

```
DB=$1
if [[ -z $DB ]]; then
 DB=$NZ_DATABASE
fi

if [[ -z $DB ]]; then
 print "Usage: install <database>"
 return 1
fi

export NZ_DATABASE="${DB}"

nzudxcompile FirstBit.cpp \
 --fenced \
 --sig   "FirstBit(varchar(any))" \
 --return  "integer" \
 --class  "FirstBit"

rm FirstBit.o_*
```

**install_bitcount.sh DBNAME**

```
DB=$1
if [[ -z $DB ]]; then
 DB=$NZ_DATABASE
fi

if [[ -z $DB ]]; then
 print "Usage: install <database>"
 return 1
fi

export NZ_DATABASE="${DB}"

nzudxcompile BitCount.cpp \
 --fenced \
 --sig   "BitCount(varchar(any))" \
 --return  "integer" \
 --class  "BitCount"

rm BitCount.o_*
```

**install_chartobase2.sh DBNAME**

```
DB=$1
if [[ -z $DB ]]; then
 DB=$NZ_DATABASE
fi

if [[ -z $DB ]]; then
 print "Usage: install <database>"
 return 1
fi

export NZ_DATABASE="${DB}"

nzudxcompile CharToBase2.cpp \
 --fenced \
 --sig   "CharToBase2(varchar(any))" \
 --return  "varchar(any)" \
 --class  "CharToBase2"

rm CharToBase2.o_*
```

Comment: great - will try this out !!

Comment: except for converting hex string to binary string, nzsql should work. For the hex string to binary string conversion, following your lead, I wrote a UDF hoping it would help compress `chartobase2(hextoraw('FFFF'))` to `hextobin('FFFF')` - the native CPP code works , however the translated Netezza UDF is not tested - do not have access to one right now.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to define a [UDF](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.udf.doc/c_udf_create_udfs.html) in C, register it with the database, and then call it on your column.

I'd start by looking at either [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205298/convert-hex-to-binary-in-c) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557400/hex-to-char-array-in-c). In both of those cases you'd likely have to strip the leading `0x`.

Answer (score 2):

following suggestions from @ScottMcG - constructing a UDF to convert hex string to binary string.

input -> 'F0F'
desired output -> '11110000111'

----------**HexToBin.cpp**------

```
#include "udxinc.h"
#include <string.h>

using namespace nz::udx;

class HexToBin : public Udf
{
    public:
        static Udf* instantiate();

    ReturnValue evaluate()
    {
        StringArg* str = stringArg(0);
        StringReturn* result = stringReturnInfo();
        result->size = str->length*4; // binary representation
        string quads[16] = {"0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101",
                     "0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011",
                     "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"};


        // iterate through the string characters 
        for(int i = 0, len = str->length; i < len; i++)
        {
            char c = str->data[i];
            // concatenate quad to result->data based on character c
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') strcat(result->data,  quads[c - '0'].c_str());
            if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') strcat(result->data,  quads[10 + c - 'A'].c_str());
            if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') strcat(result->data,  quads[10 + c - 'a'].c_str());

        }        

        NZ_UDX_RETURN_STRING(result);
    }

    uint64 calculateSize() const
    {
        return sizerStringSizeValue(sizerStringArgSize(0)*4);
    }
};

Udf* HexToBin::instantiate()
{
    return new HexToBin;
}
```

--------**install_hextobin.sh DBNAME**-------

```
DB=$1
if [[ -z $DB ]]; then
 DB=$NZ_DATABASE
fi

if [[ -z $DB ]]; then
 print "Usage: install <database>"
 return 1
fi

export NZ_DATABASE="${DB}"

nzudxcompile HexToBin.cpp \
 --fenced \
 --sig   "HexToBin(varchar(any))" \
 --return  "varchar(any)" \
 --class  "HexToBin"

rm HexToBin.o_*
```

Sample results

```
select hextobin('F0F');
   HEXTOBIN
--------------
 111100001111
(1 row)

select hextobin('00F');
   HEXTOBIN
--------------
 000000001111
(1 row)

select hextobin('F00');
   HEXTOBIN
--------------
 111100000000
(1 row)
```

Comment: I ran a quick test of this and had to make two changes to get it to work as a UDX.    I removed   "result->data =""; " and changed the result assignment to a form like this:   if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') strcat(result->data,  quads[c - '0'].c_str()); if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') strcat(result->data,  quads[10 + c - 'A'].c_str());
if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') strcat(result->data,  quads[10 + c - 'a'].c_str());  I can alter your answer to include this in more legible form if you like.

Comment: @ScottMcG  - that would be great !