# Covert an integer to binary in netezza sql

Tags: sql, netezza

I am trying to convert an integer to binary.  Here is my code

```
create table test
(test varbinary(8));

insert into test 
select int_to_string(7, binary) as test;
```

Here is the error that I get:

> ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  A size must be specified for a varying binary attribute.

Comment: I think you need to specify `base 2` instead of `binary` in  `select int_to_string(7, binary)`

Answer (score 0):

1. per [the answer proposed by ScottMcG to user3206440's related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656451/netezza-sql-convert-varchar-to-binary-string) I think it is better to use varchar(8) to store the data instead of varbinary.
2. per @rajat-mishra's hint, your `insert` statement should be:

   insert into test select int_to_string(7, 2) as test;