# Reading hex from a file

Tags: c, file, hex

I am trying to read hex values from a text file. I then need to store their individual 4 bit binary equivalents so that i can access the individual bits for comparison.
In the file the hex is in this format:

```
5104
de61
567f
```

And I would like to be able to have each line stored one at a time as binary in such a way that I can access a specific bit, maybe in an array? Like:
{0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1...}

My vague attempts at understanding C has yielded this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *file;
    char instructions[8];
    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    while(fgets(instructions, sizeof(instructions), file) != NULL){
        unsigned char a[8];
        int i = 0;
        while (instructions[i] != '\n'){
            int b;
            sscanf(&instructions[i], "%2x", &b);
            a[i] = b;
            i += 2;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Post what you tried**, and your speculation for why you thought it would work and why it seems to have failed.

Comment: Store them in bytes and use bitwise operators to check the bits

Comment: "I've tried every way I can think of" That's good. Please show your closest attempt, because good attempts at entry-level problems are usually good enough to be fixed.

Comment: You need two indexes: one for the source, one for the destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1396816/2411320). With this code you can read the file as it is.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *f;
    unsigned int num[80];
    int i=0;
    int rv;
    int num_values;

    f=fopen("test.txt","r");
    if (f==NULL){
        printf("file doesnt exist?!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (i < 80) {
        rv = fscanf(f, "%x", &num[i]);

        if (rv != 1)
            break;

        i++;
    }
    fclose(f);
    num_values = i;

    if (i >= 80)
    {
        printf("Warning: Stopped reading input due to input too long.\n");
    }
    else if (rv != EOF)
    {
        printf("Warning: Stopped reading input due to bad value.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Reached end of input.\n");
    }

    printf("Successfully read %d values:\n", num_values);
    for (i = 0; i < num_values; i++)
    {
        printf("\t%x\n", num[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, if you want to convert hex in binary, you could do it with many was. Check some links that provide methods.

1. [Convert a long hex string in to int array with sscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8197864/2411320)
2. [Source Code to Convert Hexadecimal to Binary and Vice Versa](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/hexadecimal-binary-convert)
3. [C program for hexadecimal to binary conversion](http://www.cquestions.com/2011/07/hexadecimal-to-binary-conversion-in-c.html)

Just for the reference, here is the code from the first link:

```
const size_t numdigits = strlen(input) / 2;

uint8_t * const output = malloc(numdigits);

for (size_t i = 0; i != numdigits; ++i)
{
  output[i] = 16 * toInt(input[2*i]) + toInt(intput[2*i+1]);
}

unsigned int toInt(char c)
{
  if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return      c - '0';
  if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') return 10 + c - 'A';
  if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') return 10 + c - 'a';
  return -1;
}
```